# getting deploy error during the creation of relationship onetoone beetween entities

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, entity

I-m trying to create two entities but I got the following error

```
Exception Description: Entity class [class it.volaconoi.entity.Airport] must use a @JoinColumn instead of @Column to map its relationship attribute [city].
```

These are the entities. What I would like is to connect the `city_source` to the `city` in the Airport entity and the same with the `city_dest`. Unfortunately I got that error. Without any doubt the error is due to the fact that I have created the relationship in a wrong way.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTE")
public class Route implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_ROUTE")
    private String id_route;

    @Column(name = "AIRLANE", nullable = false)
    private String airlane;

    @Column(name = "AIRCRAFT_ID", nullable = false)
    private String aircraft_id;

    @Column(name = "CITY_SOURCE", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "city", optional = false)
    private String airport_city_source;

    @Column(name = "CITY_DEST", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "city", optional = false)
    private String airport_city_dest;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTURE_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date departure_date;

    @Column(name = "ARRIVAL_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date arrival_date;

    @Column(name = "TRAVEL_CLASS", nullable = false)
    private String travel_class;

    @Column(name = "SEATS", nullable = false)
    private int seats;

    @Column(name = "PRICE", nullable = false)
    private float price;

...
```

**AIRPORT**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AIRPORT")
public class Airport implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "AIRPORT_ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    @OneToOne
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;
    @Column(name = "IATA_FAA")
    private String iata_faa_code;
    @Column(name = "ICAO")
    private String icao_code;
    @Column(name = "LATITUDE")
    private String latitude;
    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
    private String longitude;
    @Column(name = "ALTITUDE")
    private String altitude;
    @Column(name = "TIMEZONE")
    private String timezone;
    @Column(name = "DST")
    private String dst;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states, you are using the column annotation on what the JPA provider thinks should be a relationship mapping - for some reason it thinks the Airport City string is a relationship instead of a basic mapping.   Join columns are required on relationship mappings to specify both a foreign key field as well as the field in the target table that they join to, while column is used for basic mappings.

The Airport entity seems mapped correctly for the types - it shows a @Column annotation on what appear to be basic mappings, to the problem must be elsewhere.

Route's airport_city_source and airport_city_dest on the other hand are not correct, as they state that they should be mapped to columns, but are really OneToOne relationships to another entity, where that entity's city mapping defines the foreign key-join column required for this mapping.  Since the error is complaining of the city mapping being incorrect, this is likely the source.  Removing the @OneToOne will make them basic mappings which matches the String type for these attributes.

If you wanted them to map to entities, you will need to change the type to be an entity type (City perhaps?) and remove the mappedby or add a joincolumn.

You cannot link strings together like you are attempting.  Instead, maybe the Route should know the airport origin and destination, from which you can pull the city string if needed:

```
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Airport airport_source;
```

Comment: Now I have understood the problem.A relationship between entity must always be between to entity and not an entity and a plain object.

Comment: Ok...now the table has been created correctly but now I have two fields in ROUTE table: AIRPORT_CITY_DEST_AIRPORT_ID and AIRPORT_CITY_SOURCE_AIRPORT_ID. Those ones allows me to reach the correct airport. But doesn't exist a way to reach the airport through the name of the city instead of the id?

Comment: No, not in JPA.  The ID uniquely identifies an airport, not the city.  A city can have more than one airport, so this covers you.  If the city name in the Airport is unique, make it the ID/primary key instead of using a numeric aiport_id field.  Or query for the airports with a certain city name, and handle duplicates in your code.

Comment: Ok perfect I have understood everything now. Thank you very much Chris Fortunately a city can have more than one airport. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message pretty clearly tells you what's wrong: When you model a relationship, you have to specify the join column. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) for a short example, or read the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partpersist.htm#BNBPY) on the whole topic.

And an advice: The idea since Java EE 5 is to use convention over configuration, so you don't have to specify things which are default (e.g. the name).

Comment: I have already tried to put JoinColumn but without any success. I haven't understood clearly where to put JoinColumn.